# Approximate logarithm uses inaccurate approximation for log_2(1+x)-x but it still works

Tags: math, logarithm, approximation

In [this](http://www.machinedlearnings.com/2011/06/fast-approximate-logarithm-exponential.html) article a rational approximation `f(z)` for `g(z) = log_2(1 + x) - x` is used for `fastlog2` but when plotting `f(z)` and `g(z)` they look very different.

[image: plots]

Oddly enough the results of `fastlog2` are very accurate. If I adjust `f(z)` to resemble `g(z)` more closely (parabola) the results turn out to be very inaccurate.

My question is:

**Why are the results for `fastlog2` very accurate for a `f(z)` that looks very different from `g(z)` and how would you find `f(z)` for better accuracy?**

Comment: You’re missing the hack part where the bits representing the float are reinterpreted as an integer and variously twiddled. No good approximation for log₂ is going to be a parabola.

Comment: @Ryan is correct. You've overlooked the bit shift magic that makes this work.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me to understand what I was missing. But another question occurred to me: In the article the exponent is replaced by -1 which leads to 0.5*(x + 1). Can't you just replace the exponent with 0 and get the mantissa by subtracting 1 and then approximate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help from the comments I realized what my mistake was and adjusted the formula accordingly which leads to the expected result:

[image: plots]